# wandb : move runs from a blocked entity

Tags: wandb

I accidentally moved several runs from my own user account to a team entity.
Unfortunatly, this team entity had a restriction on the quantity of experiments tracked, and it now appears as blocked. I have this error message :

> Your organization is over the limit of 250 tracked hours. Please upgrade your plan to keep using W&B.

I can't find a way to move back these runs to my free account, does anyone know how to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can reach out to W&B support and they'll help with this. support@wandb.com

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought maybe there was a way to solve this with the api but I didn't find